# How to get WP GraphQL data on React front-end using Axios?

Tags: headless

I want to know how to query data from the *WP GraphQL plugin* using *Axios* on a React front-end.

I have a headless WordPress installation with the WP GraphQL plugin installed (that part is working great), but I need help understanding how to query the post data on the front-end of the site, which is built in React.

My impression is that I can call *Axios* inside of a `componentDidMount()` method, and beyond that idea, I am stuck.

```
GraphQL endpoint: https://head.mysite.com/graphql

Query:

    {
    toasters {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          toasterMeta {
            color
            brand
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`toasters` is the name of a custom post type, and in my WP GraphiQL explorer it returns the results I am expecting to see -- the query is from there.

**For example**, this normal WP API request works, but it's not GraphQL

```
axios.get("https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").then(posts => {
        this.setState({
            posts: posts.data
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi. Generally speaking, the community classes questions about third-party plugins to be off-topic. Are you sure this is not better suited to SO?

Comment: Generally speaking, I assumed there would be a WordPress developer who's mastered using this WordPress plugin and could either provide an answer or point me towards an up to date tutorial. But, I asked at SO too. (: